# display ls output in 2 columns with directories in one and files in the other

Tags: terminal, ls

Can you make an alias command that basically formats the out put of `ls` into two columns, so that the output shows all the subdirectories in column 1 and all the files in column 2.

**Example:**

```
me:~$ ls
dir1               file1.txt
dir2               file2.xml
dir3               file3.pdf
dir4               file4.png
dir5               file5.wav
dir6               file6.mp3
...                file7.doc
                   ...
```

You get the idea :) (Maybe even put the executables in column 3?)

Is this possible?

OS version: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you removed all those things @Rui F Ribeiro ? Was it too personal?

Comment: It might be in your interest keeping your posts succinct and on topic, for getting more attention and up voting. There is also a tradition of editing posts here for consistency and redundancy. See our FAQ and keep around. btw, welcome.

Comment: I will keep that in mind for future posts :D Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stat` around (you didn't comment on your OS version)? try

```
stat -c$'%F\n%n' * | awk '/^directory/ {getline LEFT[++DC]; next} {getline RIGHT[++FC]} END {for (i=1; i<=(DC>FC?DC:FC); i++) print LEFT[i], RIGHT[i]}' OFS="\t"
dir1    awkscript
dir2    fil1
dir3    file
dir4    file~
        file1
        file1~
        file2
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, only it prints column 2 relative to column 1. This makes the second column non-parallell. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: btw OS version: Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver

Comment: pipe it through `column -nt`.

Comment: There is one small problem still, in that it prints files with a whitespace in their filename in two columns... Is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: You may want to change to using formatted `printf` with sufficient field widths in the `awk` script, also eliminating the need for the `column` command.